# Magento - Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have just installed Magneto community on my win 7 (64 bit) including the 
It seemed to have gone fine but during the set up I go the error below:
Would be grateful for any idea.
tx!

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.index_process' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Run the below code in  your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `index_process` (
  `process_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Process Id',
  `indexer_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indexer Code',
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending' COMMENT 'Status',
  `started_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Started At',
  `ended_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ended At',
  `mode` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'real_time' COMMENT 'Mode',
  PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE` (`indexer_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Index Process' AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `index_process`
--

    INSERT INTO `index_process` (`process_id`, `indexer_code`, `status`, `started_at`, `ended_at`, `mode`) VALUES
    (1, 'catalog_product_attribute', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:20:11', '2014-05-03 00:20:11', 'real_time'),
    (2, 'catalog_product_price', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', 'real_time'),
    (3, 'catalog_url', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', 'real_time'),
    (4, 'catalog_product_flat', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', 'real_time'),
    (5, 'catalog_category_flat', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:11:40', '2014-05-03 00:11:40', 'real_time'),
    (6, 'catalog_category_product', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', 'real_time'),
    (7, 'catalogsearch_fulltext', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', '2014-05-03 00:29:34', 'real_time'),
    (8, 'cataloginventory_stock', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:20:11', '2014-05-03 00:20:11', 'real_time'),
    (9, 'tag_summary', 'pending', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', '2014-05-03 00:20:12', 'real_time');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try from the command line (SSH) from the Magento root to:

Reïndex all indexes: `php ./shell/indexer.php -reindexall`

Delete cache: `rm -rf var/cache/*`

Hope that helps!