# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DATABASENAMEHERE.mage_index_process' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, magento

I am getting this error -

> Magento Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'DATABASENAMEHERE.mage_index_process' doesn't exist

Below is the stack trace of the same.

```
Trace:
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mage_in...', Array)
#4 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `mage_in...', Array)
#5 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(791): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Setup.php(66): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Setup.php(45): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->_syncIndexes()
#8 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#9 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\skinbp\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

How can I resolve this or track it down?

Answer (score 0):

You should first verify that whether that table exists in your database or not.

If you couldn't find that table then create that table with dump data as per following post.

[Magento - Base table or view not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845822/magento-base-table-or-view-not-found)

Or try from command line to reindex all as described in that post

Comment: let me check that one

Comment: Ok. I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: hello emipro, still no luck here.

Comment: this is the scenario.. i downloaded everything from the live site and put it on my local machine. I'm using EasyPhp as my local server... how to use command line to reindex all in my local computer?

Comment: i've found out that the exported tables from live server are not complete.